# How to update each data of a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named class

```
|Record_No [PK] | Student_No  | Class_No  | Seat_No  |
=====================================================
|1              | 200910      | 2         | 20       |
|2              | 201234      | 2         | 13       |
|3              | 200965      | 2         | 1        |
|4              | 200920      | 2         | 8        |
|5              | 200911      | 2         | 9        |
|6              | 200955      | 1         | 10       |
|7              | 200924      | 1         | 9        |
|8              | 200922      | 1         | 1        |
|9              | 200901      | 2         | 11       |
|10             | 200902      | 2         | 18       |
```

is it possible to update the numbers in Seat_No in order from 1 up to the last count of Seat No where its class no is equal to 2?

the table should look like this:

```
|Record_No [PK] | Student_No  | Class_No  | Seat_No  |
=====================================================
|1              | 200910      | 2         | 1        |
|2              | 201234      | 2         | 2        |
|3              | 200965      | 2         | 3        |
|4              | 200920      | 2         | 4        |
|5              | 200911      | 2         | 5        |
|6              | 200955      | 1         | 10       |
|7              | 200924      | 1         | 9        |
|8              | 200922      | 1         | 1        |
|9              | 200901      | 2         | 6        |
|10             | 200902      | 2         | 7        |
```

as of now, i can only achieve this by using

```
UPDATE class SET Seat_No = 1 WHERE Class_No = 2 AND Student_No = 200910;
UPDATE class SET Seat_No = 2 WHERE Class_No = 2 AND Student_No = 201234;
...
```

and so on..

How can i solve this without putting every student_no in the query? pls help.

Comment: are you using MySQL or Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Record_No is 1-5 in your example, you can use it:

```
UPDATE class SET Seat_No = Record_No WHERE Class_No = 2
```

If not, it depends on your RDBMS.

Here is the postgresql approach:

```
UPDATE  Class C
SET     Seat_No = t.rn
FROM    (
       SELECT Record_No, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Record_No) rn
        FROM Class
       WHERE Class_no = 2
        ) t
WHERE   C.Record_No = t.Record_No
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/77645/1)

Comment: @oyan11 -- try the Fiddle Demo above -- it should work with your edits.  The Record_No was just a "quick approach" -- use the other query for your needs.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
update class
set seat_no = s.rn
from (
    select
        row_number() over(order by record_no) rn,
        record_no
    from class
    where class_no = 2
) s
where class.record_no = s.record_no
```

If you want to update all classes:

```
update class
set seat_no = s.rn
from (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by class_no order by record_no) rn,
        record_no
    from class
) s
where class.record_no = s.record_no
```

Comment: thanks, but is there another way to solve my problem without using record_no? wait, i will edit my table for clarification.

Comment: @oyan11 Your edit makes no difference in the solution. Did you try it?